# While loop is not producing multiplication table

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, multiplication

```
i = 0
d =  input("Enter the no. you want ")
while i < 11 :
    print(i * d)
    i+= 1
```

It is supposed to give multiplication table of d but it gives the following result for eg. '3' instead

```
3 

33

333

3333

33333

333333

3333333

33333333

333333333

3333333333
```

Comment: `d` is a string. typecast it to `int`.

Comment: `d` is a string, not a number. `i * d` concatenates `i` instances of `d` to itself. You'll want to attempt to parse `d` as a number using the builtin [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string not an int and if you multiply a string in Python with an integer `num`, then you will get a string repeated num times. For example,

```
s = "stack"
print(s * 3) # Returns "stackstackstack"
```

You need to use `int()` constructor to cast the input from str to int.

```
d =  int(input("Enter the no. you want "))
```

Try this:

```
d = int(input("Enter the no. you want "))
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i * d)
```

In the above code, I have replaced your `while` loop construct with [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) and [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to get sequence of numbers.

**BONUS:**

To print/display the table in a nice and better way, try the below code:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print("%d X %d = %d" % (d, i, i * d))
```

Outputs:

```
Enter the no. you want 2
2 X 1 = 2
2 X 2 = 4
2 X 3 = 6
2 X 4 = 8
2 X 5 = 10
2 X 6 = 12
2 X 7 = 14
2 X 8 = 16
2 X 9 = 18
2 X 10 = 20
```